# Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
DataClassesDataContext MyDB = new DataClassesDataContext();
var id = from wineT in MyDB.Wineries
         where wineT.wineryID==Convert.ToInt32(
             from w in MyDB.WineTypes
             where w.kind==ddlSorti.SelectedItem.Text
             select w.wineryID)
         select  wineT.name;

GridView1.DataSource = id;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I have this code and I don't have any errors, but when I start the application I get this error "Could not format node 'ClientQuery' for execution as SQL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `FirstOrDefault()` in your sub select

```
var id = from wineT in MyDB.Wineries
         where wineT.wineryID==Convert.ToInt32(
             from w in MyDB.WineTypes
             where w.kind==ddlSorti.SelectedItem.Text
             select w.wineryID).FirstOrDefault()
         select  wineT.name;
```

Comment: The first query has to return few results. With FirstOrDefault() I do get a result, but just the first one written in db.

Comment: @Katerina - We will be able to help you more effectively if you provide sample data and a sample result set